Android service started via AlarmManager in called only once
I have a mobile app that runs a certain SOAP operation every two minutes. However, I have problems with time delays when it went into deep sleep.
From the previous 2 minutes, the delay could increase up to 30 minutes depending on the phone manufacturer (I was using plain sleep interspersed with notifications).
So, after a while of figuring out what to do about it, I would like to switch to an AlarmManager (WorkManager is not implemented yet in the version of Delphi I work in) that can run the given service.
I currently have a service created as a remote service. Thanks to @Dalija Prasnikar I made some progress, but now I have a problem with repeating my service - it's called just once.
I tried to reduce the alarm interval to the minimum allowed since android API 19 (1 min), but no change.
This is called when the start button is clicked:
procedure TMainForm.SetupAlarm();
var
  Intent: JIntent;
  PendingIntent: JPendingIntent;
begin
  try
    Intent := TJIntent.Create;
    Intent.setClassName(TAndroidHelper.Context, StringToJString('com.embarcadero.services.RemoteService'));

    PendingIntent := TJPendingIntent.JavaClass.getService(TAndroidHelper.Context, 0, Intent, TJPendingIntent.JavaClass.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        TAndroidHelper.AlarmManager.setRepeating(TJAlarmManager.JavaClass.RTC_WAKEUP, 0, getTimeAfterInSecs(120),
              PendingIntent);
      except
       on E: Exception do
        Log(E.Message);
      end;
    end;

function TMainForm.getTimeAfterInSecs(Seconds: Integer): Int64;
      var
        Calendar: JCalendar;
      begin
        Calendar := TJCalendar.JavaClass.getInstance;
        Calendar.add(TJCalendar.JavaClass.SECOND, Seconds);
        Result := Calendar.getTimeInMillis;
      end;
end.

The RemoteService has these declarations:
public
    function DoStartCommand(const AStartIntent: JIntent; AFlags, AStartID: Integer): Integer; override;
    WakeLock: JPowerManager_WakeLock;
    procedure AcquireWakeLock;
    procedure ReleaseWakeLock;
  end;

Implementation:
procedure TRemoteServiceDM.ReleaseWakeLock;
begin
  if Assigned(WakeLock) and WakeLock.isHeld then
    WakeLock.release;
end;

procedure TRemoteServiceDM.AcquireWakeLock;
var
  PowerManager: JPowerManager;
begin
  PowerManager := TJPowerManager.Wrap(
    TAndroidHelper.Context.getSystemService(TJContext.JavaClass.POWER_SERVICE));

  WakeLock := PowerManager.newWakeLock(TJPowerManager.JavaClass.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, StringToJString('YourWakeLockTag'));
  WakeLock.acquire;
end;


function TRemoteServiceDM.DoStartCommand(const AStartIntent: JIntent; AFlags,
  AStartID: Integer): Integer;
begin
  try
    AcquireWakeLock;
    try
      //test
      GetSOAPService().HelloWorld;
   except
    on E: Exception do
      Log(E.Message);
    end;

    ReleaseWakeLock;
   except
   on E: Exception do
      Log(E.Message);
  end;
  Result := TJService.JavaClass.START_STICKY;
end;

Any idea why the process doesn't repeat?
The testing device is Android 11, Galaxy A12.
